# Plotting minimization graph in GA

Tags: r, plot, genetic-algorithm

The `GA` package maximize the fitness function in nature. I understand that for minization problem using `GA`, you will need to multiply your fitness with -1 in your fitness function.

```
##calling the ga() function
my_ga <- ga(...)
```

When plotting the graph (`plot(my_ga)`) for a minimization problem, I got a graph which shows a maximization pattern:

[image: which shows a maximization process]

I tried to reverse the y-axis by the changing the `ylim` in `plot()` and I got this (which is something I wanted, except for the negative y-axis):

```
## explicitly defining the y-axis
x <- seq(1.1,1.4, 0.05)
plot(my_ga, ylim=rev(range(-x)))
```

[image]

But I don't find this approach efficient at all, is there a faster way - which to change the y-axis to positive and implicitly determining the range, to plot minimization graph using the `GA` package?

*btw, just ignore the poor convergence in this example*

**[EDIT]** **- added source code**

```
library(clusterSim)
library(GA)

## data
data(data_ratio)
dataset2 <- data_ratio

## fitness function
DBI2 <- function(x) {
        cl <- kmeans(dataset2, centers = dataset2[x==1, ])
        dbi <- index.DB(dataset2, cl=cl$cluster, centrotypes = "centroids")
        score <- -dbi$DB  

        return(score)  

}

k_min <- 5

## initialization of populaton
initial_population <- function(object) {
        init <- t(replicate(object@popSize, sample(rep(c(1, 0), c(k_min, object@nBits - k_min))), TRUE))
        return(init)
}

## mutation operator
my_mutation <- function(object, parent){

        pop <- parent <- as.vector(object@population[parent, ])
        difference <- abs(sum(pop) - k_min)
        ## checking condition where there are more cluster being turned on than k_min
        if(sum(pop) > k_min){
                ## determine position of 1's
                bit_position_1 <- sample(which(pop==1), difference)
                ## bit inversion
                for(i in 1:length(bit_position_1)){
                        pop[bit_position_1[i]] <- abs(pop[bit_position_1[i]] - 1)
                } 
        } else if (sum(pop) < k_min){
                ## determine position of 0's
                bit_position_0 <- sample(which(pop==0), difference)
                ## bit inversion
                for(i in 1:length(bit_position_0)){
                        pop[bit_position_0[i]] <- abs(pop[bit_position_0[i]] - 1)
                }

        } 

        return(pop)
}

my_ga<- ga(type = "binary", 
        population = initial_population, 
        fitness = DBI2, 
        selection = ga_rwSelection,
        crossover = gabin_spCrossover,
        mutation = my_mutation,
        pcrossover = 0.8,
        pmutation = 1.0,
        popSize = 100, 
        maxiter = 100,
        seed = 212,
        nBits = nrow(dataset2))


plot(my_ga)
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: added the reproducible example

Comment: `data_ratio` isn't defined so it's not run-able.

Comment: added `data(data_ratio)` before `dataset2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, we could cheat by flipping the sign of the data in the object itself. Here's a helper function to do just that

```
flip_ga_y <- function(x) {
    x@summary <- x@summary*-1
    x
}
```

Then you can plot your sample data like

```
plot(flip_ga_y(my_ga), ylim=c(1.1,1.4))
```

Note that you will have to specify the `ylim` because the function makes some strong choices about the direction of the sign it seems. But this returns

[image]